# Non-EU Citizen. Can I get visa if my father live in Germany?

Tags: germany, eu, family

I know that this maybe is not right website to ask this kind of question, but I couldn't find any better. Maybe if you know, you could recommend me?

So here is the situation.

My father is living in Germany for 6 years already, he has osteoporosis and he can lift heavy things and move things around the house, he was in the hospital for 7 months before 2 years. His wife left him before 3 months and we plan for me to come and live with him, so I can help him and also I would really love to move to Germany. He can provide me with everything that I need to live there (place to sleep, eat and so on...)

He didn't get citizenship yet. They extended his 'classic' visa two times for 3 years, and he expected citizenship and passport this year but he needs 2 more years of working experience to get it.

Now, I am 20 years old from Serbia. I have finished high school of electrotechnics where I graduated as Electronics Technician. I also have Start Deutsch certificate 1 from Goethe-Institute. And my wish is to find some job or ausbildung.

So if anyone can tell me what are my options to get Visa?

Thank you very much!
Best Regards.

Answer (score 4):

The obvious one would be [Familienzusammenführung](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Familienzusammenf%C3%BChrung). If your father has a residency permit and a way to support you, that should be enough for you to get a residency permit (including working permit) as well.

While a lawyer might seem costly, it will save you a lot of time doing it right. If you have the money, it might be well worth it.

Comment: I am happy to hear that. He has resideny permit and he can support me. Thank you so much!